# How can I link the Google account on the android to my app?

Tags: android

I've used an app on the Android called "Noom Weight Loss", and it has a way to link your google account to the app. It presents a simple interface - that seems to be made by google - to authorize the use of my account by the app. I accept and it's working!

How does the app do that?

Is there an Google Accounts specific intent I should start or something like that?

Is it manually made by the app? If so, how?

Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without seeing exactly what you're referring to, I would suggest taking a look at the AccountManager:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html

This could be what you're looking for

Comment: It kinda is, do you have any example of this effectively being used to authenticate with other accounts in the phone? I'm having a hard time finding an example.

Comment: I've never attempted to use it before, but a quick google search came across this, which may or may not be useful:  http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/AndroidAccountManager